# Changing the Microsoft Team desktop app configuration programatically

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to change the configuration of Microsoft Teams desktop app programatically, in specific, which Camera and Microphone is selected for calls.

I did it changing the values at `%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Teams\\storage.json` but that needs to   close before doing the change and opening it after that.

Is there any way (through a Teams app or whatever) to modify these configuration options, programatically, and have them applied in a live way; without closing the app?

Comment: It is a windows issue.  Windows when a file is already open with open again only in read mode.  To be able to write you need to close the app that opened the file in read/write mode.

Comment: @jdweng: It has nothing to do with file sharing modes, only with whether the application considers the config file or its in-memory copy of the configuration to be authoritative.  If the in-memory data structure is authoritative, the config file gets overwritten and that can happen on any OS, any filesystem.

Comment: It allows to write the file, that's not a problem. The issue is that Teams is not going to read that file until the app is closed and open. 

In the meantime Teams apps is running it's just open/write/closing the file each time it wants to persist a new value.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Absolutely wrong with windows.

Comment: @jdweng: You are accurately describing a completely different problem, but it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Read the question.  The OP want to modify the file without closing the app.  If the APP opened the file in read/write mode another app cannot write to the file.

Comment: @jdweng: You aren't paying attention to the facts provided by OP.  He succeeds in overwriting the file.  The app ignores his changes while it is running.  You jumped to a conclusion that there is some I/O error while opening or writing the file, which the OP never said, and now has clarified succeeds.